# Updating a webpart on sharepoint without refreshing the page using JQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have a Calendar event -displaying webpart. But it gets updated only on page refresh. I want it to be updated as and when i synchronize the events from outlook calendar to sharepoint calendar. How should I do it using JQuery. I am new to JQuery. Kindly help

Comment: i have synchronizes the outlook events to the sharepoint calendar. Then the list of events will appear as notification on a webpart. But the updates are reflected on page refresh only(since i have written the coding in page load). Now I want the update to happen withour page refresh or rekoad.

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: SPSite spsite;                                                   SPWeb spweb;
SPList calendar;
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e){
base.OnInit;
InitializeControl();}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
spsite = new SPSite("url");
spweb = spsite.OpenWeb();
calendar = spweb.Lists["Calendar"];
foreach (SPListItem item in calendar.Items){
Label lbl = new Label();
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "imgurl";
placeholder.Controls.Add(img);
lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(item["Title"])+"</br>"+Convert.ToString(item["StartTime"])+"</br>";
placeholder.Controls.Add(lbl);}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering why you want the webpart to be updated automatically? Will it be displayed on a webpage that is constantly open? Otherwise you would want to display the data after visiting the page?

If you want the data updated without a page refresh you have some options. When it is enough to do a manual update, you can use an updatepanel and a refesh button on the webpart. Then when pressing the refresh button only the webpart content will be refreshed. When using this method you can keep your code like it is implemented now.

If you want to have it automatically updated, you will need to change your webpart so the data is retrieved client side. To do this you will need the help of the client object model or call the sharepoint services with javascript. You can then use a javascript timer to retrieve the data for ex. every minute.